# Cannot find users after importing project into new Firebase console

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am upgrading my project from `Firebase.com` to `console.firebase.google`.  i have follow the steps on the migration guide on the below link.

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#import_your_project_to_the_new_firebase_console_numbered

The database imported successfully but my user not able to imported from the firebase to goole console.
I need the help regarding this. Any helpful answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: If your users were not migrated, please reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/). Be sure to include your app name/project id (https://<app-name>.firebaseio.com) in the description.

Comment: It turns out we have some back up in the user migration queue. Your app was working, but indeed it took longer than usual to show user in the console. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/vfEWlzRgOaE

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the comment. it takes full day to get my old users but now all my older user are back into the app thnks again.

Comment: Yeah, we had to temporarily pause the use migration process. Sorry about the delay! Keep in mind: your existing users were not affected by this, their data stayed where it was. It just wasn't shown to you, since you project was already on the new console.

Comment: Many Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> Your user data is automatically migrated to the new authentication backend. This happens in the background and your users can continue to use the app while the data is being migrated. User signups and logins will not be affected. While the system is migrating user accounts, you will see a spinner in the Auth tab of the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

You could wait for a while as this is a background process, and can you see a spinner in the **Auth Tab** to confirm users are being synced or not ?

Comment: i have checked that All my Userdata migrated but no user in Auth tab migrated from the previous version of the project.